# How to configure `ng serve` to catch changes in a dockersized Angular 2 app?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, angular-cli

I am 'dockersizing' (I hope this is the right term) an existing Angular 2 app, running on `angular-cli` (1.0.0-beta.31).

I am struggling to find a way to make `ng serve` catch whenever I update a file in my working directory and therefore - refresh my app (as usual). Otherwise, I need to `docker-compose up --build` every time I change a file...

**EDIT**: The idea I'm exploring is to add a volume.

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Dockerizing Angular 2 Client App
# @link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-and-docker-compose

# Create image based on the official Node 7 image from dockerhub
FROM node:7

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
# **EDIT**: comment out this, so I can set-up a volume
# COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# specify docker-compose version
version: '2'

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  angular2app: # name of the service
    build: ./ # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" # specify port forewarding
    # **EDIT**: Setting-up the volume here
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

**EDIT**: Without the volume config - the app builds and runs successfully. After setting up the volume, error output:

```sh
Building angular2app
Step 1/7 : FROM node:7
 ---> b3a95b94bd6c
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2afb01ffe055
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 44d08fdb4a19
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87bb4f71c13c
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba88a0e1e480
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 4200
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4fddacae8486
Step 7/7 : CMD npm start
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c5ac29bf85fc
Successfully built c5ac29bf85fc
Creating minterface_angular2app_1

ERROR: for angular2app  Cannot start service angular2app: Mounts denied: closed
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

How to configure `ng serve` to catch changes in my current working directory and to re-build my Angular 2 app?

PS: I am with **docker-compose** version 1.11.1 (build 7c5d5e4), running on **Mac** (Sierra 10.12.3) via **Docker for Mac**.

Comment: What is your current working directory? In Docker for Mac, only a few locations from your Host system are usable as volumes.

Comment: `/Users/<my-user>/Sites/<my-project>` is my current working directory.

Comment: Can you try to run `docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app debian ls -lah` from the same directory and check the output? It should look like what a local call to `ls -lah` looks like regarding access rights. In case you have general problem with Docker, it should exit with a comparable error.

Comment: @AlexanderBlock I am getting an error: `docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: closed.` / `ERRO[0013] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled`. Maybe this is a lead?

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your Docker for Mac installation. Please try another command: `docker run --rm -ti -v /:/host` debian ls -lah /host/Users` and then `docker run --rm -ti -v /:/host` debian ls -lah /host/Users/<my-user>/Sites/<my-project>`. If both fail, I'd recommend to reinstall Docker for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.
Webpack was not watching for changes.
See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Inside webpack.common.js, you can add

```
watchOptions: {
   poll: 1000, // a poll interval in milliseconds
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor
Just run the process using that supervisor process and specify which folders it should watch `-w` for changes and restart.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This solution won't solve my core problem. My actual question is related to how to tweak the Docker configuration to meet my goal.

Comment: `COPY . /usr/src/app` - in dockerfie, should be removed

Add volume in your docker-compose.yml
`volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app`

if in npm start you have `ng serve` then it should work as you will be sharing files with host and each change will be included inside container. Before you only copied once and then changes would not progress into container.

You can read about volumes syntax in here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: When I run `docker-compose up --build` I am getting this error after the changes you suggested: `ERROR: for angular2app Cannot start service angular2app: Mounts denied: closed
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: what version of docker and docker-compose do you use ? Windows, Mac, Linux ?

Comment: docker-compose version 1.11.1 (build 7c5d5e4), running on Mac (Sierra 10.12.3) via [Docker for Mac](https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac)

Comment: could you paste your current docker-compose  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136574/discussion-between-jacek-lawniczak-and-kaloyan-kosev).

Comment: yes, I updated the question by adding the edited lines in my `Dockerfile` and in my `docker-compose.yml` files. See the "EDIT:" lines.

Comment: Two options: You might be out of memory for docker or if you take a look at docker > preferences ... [ file sharing ] take a look if it has default settings (/Users, /Volumes, /tmp, /private) also try to add memory in [ Advanced ] and restart, see if that helps

Comment: 1) I have the default sharing settings in "File Sharing" section: ( /Users, /Volumes, /tmp, /private directories are up). 2) I increased the memory up to 6GB in "Advanced", there is no change. Same error occurs :(

Comment: Try adding a `.dockerignore` file with `node_modules` and other large files in it.

Comment: @jkinkead I have a `.dockerignore` file with `node_modules` in there. Same result :(

Comment: were you able to get this to work? I am having the same issues

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer you are after, but it is how we solve this problem in our dev workflow:

1. Don't run `ng serve` in docker. Run it on your host. This way you avoid all the bugs of file sharing with docker. And you will hit them for sure, there are known issues with file changes on host propagating to Docker VM.
2. Setup a reverse proxy in `docker-compose` that proxies requests to your backend and angular project. Most probably, you already are doing that.

   ```
   web:
     image: nginx
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     links:
       - backend
     extra_hosts:
       - "frontend:192.168.99.1"
   ```

   Note that, instead of linking to `frontend`, we specify `extra_hosts` to point to our host IP address.
3. Add the IP address to your lo0 interface on host, so that it is accessible from inside docker VM.

   ```
   sudo ifconfig lo0 inet 192.168.99.1/32 add
   ```

   This setting doesn't persist on a restart, so you will do it again.

The only thing to take care of here is to select a sane IP address to avoid conflicts with your local network and any VPN software you may be using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I couldn't implement your suggestion. Maybe if you share a complete configuration example I might be able to (with a `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` and everything). Anyways I am still wondering what's the best practice here.  I see that Angular 2 team is planning to [add convenience for users to containerize and deploy their Angular application via Docker](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/docker-deploy.md). I am looking forward to it. Thanks for your response, @Tair

Comment: @KaloyanKosev why do you want to run Angular app in docker? Looking at your configuration, I see that you expose port 4200 directly from docker, why not just `ng serve` on your host then? Your app will be still accessible at http://localhost:4200